# How can I draw a line segment from an anchor node inside a pic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, nodes, tikz-pic

I'm trying to draw a line from an anchor node inside a configurable object constructed as a TikZ pic, but it doesn't work. Is there an explanation and solution for this?

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}  

\begin{document}
% --- Manômetro ---------------------
\tikzset{pics/manometer/.style={code={
      \tikzset{manometer/.cd,#1}
      \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manometer/##1}}% local object variable
      %------------------------------
%--- case
  \filldraw [thin,fill=\pv{case color}, opacity=0.95] (0,0) circle (2.05cm); 
  \draw [semithick, white,opacity=0.95] (0,0) circle (1.85cm); 
% --- Tubo de Bourdon interno
  \pv{bourdon}[double=white, line width=0.5pt,double distance=2mm,opacity=0.95, rounded corners, cap=round] (-90:1.95) --++(90:0.5) arc(270:20:1.4cm) coordinate(ptb);

  \pv{bourdon}(ptb) -- (0,0);
  \filldraw[black,thin,fill=white, opacity=0.9] (0,0) circle (1.8cm); 

% --- pressure port node for an external reference
  \node (-port) at (0,-1.78){} ;
%--- escala
  \foreach \angle / \label in 
    {225/0, 200/10, 175/20, 150/30, 125/40, 100/50, 75/60,  50/70, 25/80, 0/90,-25/100 } 
  { 
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.6cm) -- (\angle:1.8cm); 
    \draw (\angle:1.3cm) node{\textsf{\label}}; 
  } 

  \draw (-90:0.75cm) node{\SI{}{\kilo\pascal}}; % unidade

  \foreach \angle  in {225,222.5, ..., -25} {\draw[thin] (\angle:1.7cm) -- (\angle:1.8cm);} 
  \foreach \angle  in {225,212.5, ..., -25} {\draw[thin] (\angle:1.65cm) -- (\angle:1.8cm);} 

  \draw[circle,ultra thick,-latex] (0,0) to[short,*-](225-\pv{value}*2.5:1.1cm); % Valor indicado 
  \draw[fill=black,rounded corners] (0,0) -- (225-\pv{value}*2.5-30:-5mm) -- +(225-\pv{value}*2.5-90:5mm) --  cycle;

  \node[draw,circle, fill=gray!10, opacity=0.85] at(0,0){};
    }
  }, % end of code
  manometer/.cd,
  value/.initial=30,
  case color/.initial=cyan!60!gray,
  port color/.initial=green!30!black,
  pressure port/.initial=\draw, %\path % to hide pressure port
  bourdon/.initial=\draw, %\path % to hide bourdon tube
} % End of Manometer

\begin{tikzpicture} 
% defining a pic with name P01
% The problem is that the connection port is outside of the object.
\pic [local bounding box=P01] at (0,0) {manometer={value=50, port color=olive!50!gray, pressure port=\draw, bourdon=\path}};

  \draw[color=green!50!black, double=cyan!1, line width=2mm, double distance=1mm, opacity=0.95, rounded corners] (P01.-90) --++(0,-1) --++(-2,0) ;


%--- Following is the desired method using an internal node reference  to connect the object but  the following error occurs:
% Package pgf Error: No shape named `pgfcirc@short2122start' is known. ...gray, pressure port=\draw, bourdon=\path}}

\pic (P02) at (5,0) {manometer={value=50, pressure port=\draw, bourdon=\draw}};
\draw[color=green!50!black, double=cyan!1, line width=2mm, double distance=1mm, opacity=0.95, rounded corners] (P02-port) --++(0,-1) --++(2,0) ;

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image: Manometer without and with an internal port connection]

Comment: Please complete your code fragment, that we can see, what is your problem. Te best extend it to small compilable document with your picture..

Comment: @AnisioBraga in the last two lines of code -- where is the port  `P01` defined

Comment: @jsbibra I used *local bounding box* to name the pic node [ ''' \pic [local bounding box=P01] at (0,0) {manometer}''' and reference to it using using P01.-90" since I couldn't get rid of the reported error inserted as a comment in the code.

Comment: Why didn't you want to use `[local bounding box=P02]` and same definition as `(P02.-90) --++(0,-1) --++(2,0) ;`

Comment: The node indexing "P02-port" is a descriptive name that can be placed anywhere inside a picture. The "local bounding box" was an interim attempt until @gernot explained the incompatibility of circuitikz and pic. Using only TikZ avoids all the snag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `circuitikz` elements inside a tikz pic. Here is a rather minimal example producing a similar error as the original code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}  
\tikzset{pics/mypic/.style={code={\draw (0,0) to[short](1,0);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (p) {mypic};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The source of the problem seems to be the naming of nodes. If you don't name the concrete instance of `mypic`, i.e., if you remove `(p)`, then the error disappears.

As an alternative, use plain tikz and draw the hand of the manometer with tikz commands. This shouldn't be more difficult than using `circuitikz` elements for situations they were not intended for.

Comment: Thanks @gernot for excellent tip.  I've used circuitikz as a superset of TikZ, but I was unaware of  node naming conflicts!